# Java code from javascript

Tags: javascript, java

How I write java code from javascript that will complete in server. Please help me.
I have long been trying to remake it
It is query to server to will be logged.

```
this.login = function(options) {
//It is query to server to will be logged.
    if (typeof (options.success) == "function" && typeof (options.error) == "function" && options.params != null) {
        var successCallback = options.success;
        var errorCallback = options.error;
    } else {
        AV.console.error(LP + 'Invalid number of arguments (min req = 3), Please read API Documentation.');
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _sURL + '/csportal/v1/login',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(options.params),
        success: function(response) {
            AV.console.debug(LP + "login::Success: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            if (response && response.success == true) {
                _userLoggedIn = 'true';
                _userReturned = 'false';
                _userInfo = response.data;
                successCallback({"message": response.message,"data": response.data});
            } else {
                _userLoggedIn = 'false';
                errorCallback({message: response.message});
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            AV.console.warn(LP + "login:: error: " + e.message);
            errorCallback({message: e.responseText});
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: can you edit your question? it's hard figuring out what exactly you are asking

Comment: what you want ? do you want sent 'java code' to server side or do you just want to call to server via ajax(jquery) ?

Comment: I want to make the same request to the server and not with the client from the server in java server, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Do you mean how to develop server side correspond with your client request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here.

**Option 1** - Corresponding to your  _sURL + '/csportal/v1/login, you need to create a class extending HttpServlet class, override the post method and return required response. Or if you are using any frameworks (like Spring MVC or Struts), you just need to override corresponding Action classes.

**Option 2** - Corresponding to your _sURL + '/csportal/v1/login, you create a REST api (using Jersey), and write a POST method handling JSON request and return required RESPONSE.

If you don't have server side experience, consider catching a server side engineer from your team for help.

Comment: I did not properly explained, I want to make a request to csportal / login to the server in java is the same as with your browser